# Can't Install Google TV SDK

Tags: android, sdk, google-tv

Using SDK Manager it shows Android 3.1 (API12) and that shows Google TV by Google Inc. is not installed.  When I click the check box the 'Install Packages' stays greyed out.  When I click any of the other not installed the Install Packages un-greys and shows 1 Package to install.  I've restarted the SDK Manager and still te same.

Here is a picture of [image: SDK Manager].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
(2013-01-24)
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_addon#Prerequisites

> Note: As of Google TV Add-on API Level 13, Google TV emulation is available for Linux, Windows and OS X.

for now(2011-10-20) Google TV SDK **IS WORKING ONLY ON LINUX**

menu Pakages->Show Archives Details and you will see:
[image]

also see http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/tv/android/docs/gtv_addon.html section Prerequisites

Comment: Why even show it if you can't install it...ugh!  I just wish they had a Bluetooth working on the emulator so  can debug my code without have to install to phone all the time.

Comment: @JPM SDK 14 seems to be buggy